# NullPointerException in YouTube API v3

Tags: java, youtube, nullpointerexception, youtube-data-api

I have been working with the YouTube API v3 with Java and have encountered a problem.

When trying to set a variable in an array I am getting a NullPointerException. It seems completely random and impossible. I am getting this on this line:

`full[0] = snippet.getDisplayMessage().toLowerCase();`

in this method:

```
private static void listChatMessages(
        final String liveChatId,
        final String nextPageToken,
        long delayMs) {
        System.out.println(
            String.format("Getting chat messages in %1$.3f seconds...", delayMs * 0.001));
        Timer pollTimer = new Timer();
        pollTimer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Get chat messages from YouTube
                        LiveChatMessageListResponse response = youtube
                            .liveChatMessages()
                            .list(liveChatId, "snippet, authorDetails")
                            .setPageToken(nextPageToken)
                            .setFields(LIVE_CHAT_FIELDS)
                            .execute();

                        // Display messages and super chat details
                        List<LiveChatMessage> messages = response.getItems();
                        for (int i = 0; i < messages.size(); i++) {
                            LiveChatMessage message = messages.get(i);
                            LiveChatMessageSnippet snippet = message.getSnippet();
                            final String[] full = new String[2];
                            full[0] = snippet.getDisplayMessage().toLowerCase();
                            full[1] = message.getId();
                            ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
                            es.submit(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    PressKey.main(full);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        // Request the next page of messages
                        listChatMessages(
                            liveChatId,
                            response.getNextPageToken(),
                            response.getPollingIntervalMillis());
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        System.err.println("Throwable: " + t.getMessage());
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, delayMs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure how the API is implemented, but this NPE happens because the value of

```
snippet.getDisplayMessage()
```

Is `null`, and calling `.toLowerCase()` on `null` results in the NPE.

Like I said, I do not know for sure how the API and the container classes are implemented, but it may seem like `getDisplayMessage()` is not always guaranteed to return any content.

You could fix your NPE by checking for null values and supplying a default value instead:

```
full[0] = snippet.getDisplayMessage() == null ? "" : snippet.getDisplayMessage().toLowerCase();
```

Here we assign an empty string to `full[0]` if `getDisplayMessage()` is `null`.

Comment: I will accept your answer when I can (it wants me to wait 7 mins now.)